# How to store predicates in configuration file in java

Tags: java

I have a `list` of `hashmap<string, real>`. I want to access each element on the list, apply a `predicate` on it and add the element to another list if the predicate returns true.

For example suppose I have a list of hashmap like this - `{(a, 15), (b, 17), (c, 12)}, {(a, 12), (b, 13), (d, 90)}`. My predicate would be something like `a > 7 & b < 15` . Now I would apply this predicate on each element of the list and will find that the second element satisfy the predicate. 
Applying the predicate should be easy as all I have to do is to access the element and compare its value with values supplied with predicate.

The part where I am stuck is how to save such a `predicate` in a `configuration` file, such that it can be easily converted into a class and new predicates can be added without fiddling with core code.

Comment: You're looking to convert text into an algorithm, so you're really looking for a general lexer/parser or scripting language. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3422673/1426891), which discusses some libraries (including Java 6's built-in Javascript engine) and how to write your own.

Comment: Perhaps an easier approach, if the scope of the predicates could be easily limited to a few particular cases, is to offer a set of predefined predicates, and in the configuration class use the class name and a number of parameters that work with that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `nashorn` javascript engine. Write a java script validation function for each predicate, and store it in a java script file.

```
function pred1(a,b)
{
    if(a>7 && b<15) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Create and load the predicate file. You need to mention all the predicate file paths in a configuration file, and lookup their paths from the configuration file.

```
Properties property = new Properties();
property.load(configuration file path goes here);
```

Sample `configuration` file property:

```
predicatefileList:test1.js,...
```

Get the property,

```
String[] filePaths = ((String)property.get("predicatefileList")).split(",");
```

Initialize and use the script engine.

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
// use filePaths here  instead of the file name.
ScriptObjectMirror s = (ScriptObjectMirror)engine.eval("load(\"test1.js" + "\");");
```

For each `map` in the `list`, call the `predicate function` by passing the `arguments` to the `predicate` function:

```
list.forEach(map->{
            System.out.println(s.call(map.get("a"), m.get("b")));
});
```